# Maven deployment

Tags: java, maven

```
mvn clean deploy -P PROD
```

What does this code do?

```
mvn jetty:run
```

I have a war file, do i need to run this deploy code too... i am bit confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd advise you to read the [Deploy plugin documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/), ditto for [the Jetty one](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jetty-maven-plugin/usage.html).

From what I can see, `mvn clean deploy` cleans your project (suppresses compiled files), and then compiles and deploy it. `mvn jetty:run` launches the jetty server.

If you're completely new to Maven, it's a build system, to help you manage your dependencies and your application lifecycle. You can read more about it on the [Maven site](http://maven.apache.org/).

Answer (score 1):

> clean deploy

I suggest you read up on the [Maven Build Lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) to get full details on these.

> -P PROD

This runs the build under the `PROD` [profile](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html); presumably it is your production build.